# Why does the Sliding effect on my JPanel sometimes lag?

Tags: java, swing, lag

I am changing the bounds of a `JPanel` using a `Timer` to get a sliding effect when someone hovers over a particular rectangular area, this is working as expected. There are buttons in the `JPanel` and they have different `MouseEvent` behaviors. But *SOMETIMES* it starts lagging or slides very slowly. Please, can anyone suggest what can I do, to ensure it performs well every time?

**EDITED:**

The `buttonsPanel` have `button` in it. `buttonsPanel` is added to a `JLayeredPane` which have bounds as `rect`. When JLayeredPane or JButton `button` is `hovered` mouse events are triggered. Mouse events then triggers the timer to `slide the buttonsPanel` and bring to it view.

```
class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private static final int frames = 50;
    int count = 0;
    private final Timer timer = new Timer(1, this);

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (count >= frames) {
            timer.stop();
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
            buttonsPanel.setBounds(hidden_width - hidden_width * count / frames, 0, hidden_width, frameHeight);
        }
    }
}

class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private MyActionListener timerListener;

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(final MouseEvent event) {

        final Color color = new Color(50, 50, 50);
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            final JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            button.setBackground(color);
            buttonsPanel.setVisible(true);
        } else if (!buttonsPanel.isVisible()) {
            buttonsPanel.setVisible(true);
            timerListener = new MyActionListener();
            timerListener.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(final MouseEvent event) {
        Point point = new Point(0, 0);
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
            final JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
            point = button.getLocation();
            button.setBackground(Windows8GUI.color);
        }
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, hidden_width, frameHeight);
        if (!rect.contains(point.x + event.getX(), point.y + event.getY())) {
            buttonsPanel.setVisible(false);
            buttonsPanel.setBounds(0, 0, hidden_width, frameHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry bad name... that is the JPanel which have buttons in it.

Comment: Can you show where you are creating the gui? Perhaps the main method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue is you are assuming that you have control over the paint engine.  You don't, in fact, the paint engine is at the mercy of the OS.  This means that you can jump up and down all you like, but until the OS and Java's paint engine are ready, nothing will happen.

In fact, if you call repaint repeatedly in quick succession you can find yourself flooding the paint engine with requests, slowing it down even further.

While not a solution to the whole problem, it will make your life vastly simpler take a look at the [TimingFramework](http://java.net/projects/timingframework) or [Trident](http://kenai.com/projects/trident/pages/Home).

They are "animation" frameworks designed to take out the guess work and make your life easier.  I personal use `TimingFramework` for all my animation and it works well.

The timing frameworks work on a % over time.  That is, you give it a time for a cycle and the frameworks will return a % value based on how far through that cycle they are.  You can apply interpolations, allowing you to effect how fast a portion of the animation will play.

`Trident` has also been designed to provide the means to call other methods on your behalf, so it could set the bounds of the button pane for you, based on values you supply it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot, but using another framework for just a simple task looks like a lot of work. But I know the reason now, that's what more important. I increased the timer delay as suggested by Roland and it worked, though it is not as smooth (not a big deal) as it was before but the performance is consistent now.

Answer (score 3):

> In fact, if you call repaint repeatedly in quick succession you can find yourself flooding the paint engine with requests, slowing it down even further.

I think this is the real problem. Try increasing the delay between the timer events from 1 to 10-50 and it should run a lot better.

For a lot of how-tos for building those (and a lot of other) effects, I can only recommend the Book [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/). On this page you also find a lot of examples for those effects handled in the book.

Comment: I changed the frames and delay to 10 and it worked. Thanks a lot. I'll surely buy that book.